# Show that the restriction of $q$ to $\widetilde{A}$ is a covering space

Tags: general-topology

Let $q:\widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$ be a covering space. Let $A \subseteq X$ and $\widetilde{A}= q^{-1}(A)$. Show that the restriction of $q$ to $\widetilde{A}$ is a covering space.

I know there is a similar question like this but really didnt get the solution there and my problem is still a bit different so I try again here.

My attempt: Assume $q$ is a covering map and let $B_n$ be evenly covered subsets of $X$. Then the family of all such $B_n$ is an open cover of $X$. We want to show that $q|_A:A\rightarrow \widetilde{A}$ is a covering space. The restriction is a covering map if $A$ is connected and locally path-connected and for every $a \in \widetilde{A}$, $a$ has an evenly covered neighborhood. The later is true since $\widetilde{A}$ is a universal covering space so every element must have an evenly covered neighborhood. Now how do I get from here?

Comment: If $A$ is arbitrary when $A$ cannot be connected and locally path connected. And I suppose you want $g|_{\tilde A} \tilde A \to A$.

Comment: Why do you need anything to be connected and locally path-connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y \in A$, then let $U_y$ be an evenly covered neighbourhood of $y$ for $q$, so that $q^{-1}[U_y]$ is a pairwise disjoint union of open sets $V_i, i \in I$ and for each $i$, $q\restriction_{V_i}$ is a homeomorphism between $V_i$ and $U_y$.

Then we can take $U_y \cap A$ as the evenly covered neighbourhood for $q\restriction_{\tilde{A}}: q^{-1}[A] \to A$. This works as it is relatively open by definition and $q^{-1}[U_y \cap A]= q^{-1}[U_y] \cap \tilde{A}$ and these are a pairwise disjoint union of $V_i \cap \tilde{A}$ and the further restrictions preserve the homeomorphic nature of $q$ on those sets.

This is all you need to remark. Nothing to do with universal coverings or local path-connectedness; just use the definition of a covering map.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in A$ and let $U\subset X$ be open neighborhood of $x$ such that $q^{-1}(U)=\cup_j V_j$ where $V_j\cap V_i=\emptyset$ and $V_j\approx U$ for all $j$. Then $U\cap A$ is open in $A$ and $q^{-1}(U\cap A)=\cup_j (V_j\cap \tilde{A})$ satisfies $V_j\cap \tilde{A}\approx U\cap A$ (check this!) and $(V_j\cap \tilde{A})\cap (V_i\cap \tilde{A})=\emptyset$. The definition of a covering space.